# Formatting an array output in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, formatting, string-formatting

I am trying to create a method that sums and outputs integers in an array. I understand how to sum the integers, however I am having trouble producing the desired output.

If I pass into the method 8, 3, 3
I need the output to look as follows.

For the list = <8, 3, 3> the sum is: 14

Once again I am familiar with how to sum, I am unfamiliar with how to format this.
Here is my method so far...

```
public static void Sum(params int[] number)
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; ++i)
      {
         total = total + number[i];
      }

    Console.Write("For the list =, the sum of its elements is : {0}.", total);
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```

Comment: String.Join() is the easy and elegant answer, but for learning: You have to break up the Write() part into a head, a body with a for-loop and a tail.

Comment: hey thanks. I understood that concept, however the formatting wasn't quite right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `String.Join` method to make a string with the values in the array:

```
string values = String.Join(", ", number);
```

Then just add it to the output:

```
Console.Write("For the list = <{0}> the sum of its elements is : {1}.", values, total);
```

---

Prior to framework 4 there is no overload of `String.Join` that can take an array of anything other than string, so if you are using an older framwork you need to turn the integers to strings:

```
string values = String.Join(", ", number.Select(n => n.ToString()));
```

Comment: You'll need to convert the items to strings in the array.. since `string.Join` takes a string array..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: You only need to do that if you are using a framework older than 4. I just added a paragraph about that.

Comment: Thanks Guys...That is doing the trick. I need to look into the .Join method a little more. very handy.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Sum(params int[] number)
{
    int total=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; ++i) total = total + number[i];
    string ext = String.Format ("<{0}>", String.Join (",", number));

    Console.Write("For the list ={0} the sum is: {1}.",ext,  total);
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Sum(8,3,3);
    }

    public static void Sum(params int[] number)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("For the list <{0}>, the sum of its elements is: {1}", 
            string.Join(", ", number), 
            number.Sum());
    }   
}
```

outputs:

> For the list <8, 3, 3>, the sum of its elements is: 14

[Click here for a working sample](http://ideone.com/9TeMIm)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could go to produce the desired output, one would be:
public static void Sum(params int[] number)

```
{
    int total=0;
    StringBuild tmp="For the list =
    for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; ++i)
      {
         total = total + number[i];

      }
    Console.Write("For the list =, the sum of its elements is : {0}.", total);
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```