# How to format an array of numbers into a string in C#?

Tags: c#, string, formatting, type-conversion, format

The method `String.Format` has [the following overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-8.0#system-string-format(system-string-system-object())):

```
public static string Format (string format, params object?[] args);
```

which I supposed was meant for formatting many `args` of the same type into a string with *a format for each* of the `args`, similarly to `str.format(*args)` in python 3.

However, when I call:

```
var a = String.Format("{0} {1:0.00000000e+000} {2:0.00000000e+000}", new Double[] {1,2,3} );
```

I get the error:

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

When I would expect the output in `a` to be

```
"1 2.00000000e+000 3.00000000e+000"
```

similarly to `a="{0:d} {1:1.8e} {2:1.8e}".format(*[1,2,3])` in python 3.

Calling

```
var a = String.Format("{0}", new Double[] {1,2,3} );
```

fixes the error but returns in `a` the wrong result:

```
"System.Double[]"
```

What is the correct c# way to get the python result I expected (with different formatting for the first column)?

-

PS: [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218555/formatting-an-array-output-in-c-sharp) gives me an insight, but I'm sure there's an easier way that I'm missing:

```
String.Concat((new Double[] { 1,2,3 }).Select(k => string.Format("{0}", k)))
```

this can't be the best (or *correct*) way. Specially because it makes the overload `String.Format(String, params object[])` useless, IMHO.

Comment: I know an ugly probably not the best way, which cannot achieve different formatting: `String.Concat((new Double[] { 1,2,3 }).Select(k => string.Format("{0}", k)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an `object` array instead of a `double` array fixes the problem:

```cs
string a = String.Format("{0} {1:0.00000000e+000} {2:0.00000000e+000}", 
                      new object[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

The problem is that since you are not passing an `object[]` but a `double[]`, C# assumes that this double array is a single parameter of the params array which is of type `object[]`, i.e. it passes the method an object array containing a single item being a double array.

```cs
new object[] { new double[] { 1, 2, 3 } }
```

If the double values are given as an array variable, you could write:

```cs
double[] d = [1, 2, 3]; // C# 12 collection expression
string a = String.Format("{0} {1:0.00000000e+000} {2:0.00000000e+000}",
                         d.Cast<object>().ToArray());
```

Since the parameter is a `params` array, we can also simply write

```cs
string a = String.Format("{0} {1:0.00000000e+000} {2:0.00000000e+000}", 1, 2, 3);
```

Or we can use string interpolation where the numbers do not represent indexes but are the ones we want to format

```cs
string a = $"{1} {2:0.00000000e+000} {3:0.00000000e+000}";
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `string.Join()` will work to do this for joining items of an array.

```
double[] d = new double[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
string s = string.Join(" ", d);
```

This joins the values into a string and any delimiter can be added in the first parameter of `string.Join()`.

To get the desired output of the formatted string, a `Cast<object>()` is needed. This will cast it to an array of objects which `string.Format` accepts, which is why simply passing in a `double[]` to `string.Format` fails and throws the exception.

```
object[] args = d.Cast<object>().ToArray();
string x = string.Format("{0} {1:0.00000000e+000} {2:0.00000000e+000}", args);
```

I hope this answers your question. Other than this, a loop might work for formatting the string if an unknown amount of objects need to be formatted.

Comment: This partially solves the problem, although it doesn't take care of the different formatting for each column... If I would need to use `String.Join`, what is the point of having the overload `String.Format(String, params object[])`?